# How to use smart app banner of ios in our website

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, smartbanner

I am using smart app banner of ios in our website.I write the below code in my banner.html page but when i hit banner.html in safari browser of iphone it is not showing any kind of banner.Is i am doing any thing wrong or is there any mistake in my code.

My web code for smart app banner.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Math Ninja iPhone/iPod Touch Game | Making Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, and Division Fun!</title>
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=370144476"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
```

Please Help me,
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Which version of iOS is running on your iPhone ? I put your HTML code in an index.html and it works :

[image]

Comment: Strange ! Can you put your HTML file online ?

Comment: I have tested your link on 2 different devices and it works. Have you tested to reset your device settings ? (cf the link I've posted : Open Settings, find General, then go into Reset and Reset All Settings. )

Answer (score 0):

To add a Smart App Banner to your website, include the following meta tag in the head element of each page where you’d like the banner to appear:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, app-argument=myURL">
```

the full doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners